# Java how to return a function that returns a 2d array right angle pattern

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

Consider a set of number grids like:

```
1      1  2      1  2  3
       2  2      2  2  3
                 3  3  3
```

In other words, a square grid where the number in each position follows a right-angle pattern. How do I write a function that creates, fills in, and returns such a 2d array?

( Also, I'm wondering if Math.max(a, b) would be useful for filling in the grid. I'm wondering if it could return which value is greater between two inputs a and b.)

I already have a function set up, but I don't know where to start:

```
int[][] cornerPattern(int squareSize) {

}
```

Hints would be fine

Comment: Honestly, don't you see a pattern here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most of the java programs can easily be solved or atleast initiated by finding a pattern. 
So whats the pattern here? 
The pattern is that the relation between array index and the element at that place. 
 Every index which has 0 in it has 1 so arr[0][0] is 1.See the pattern there? 
 Every index which has [1] in it has 2. So arr[0][1], arr[1][0] and arr[1][1] are 2 and same is the condition with 3.  
 The size of the array is also defined in the same way. 3, will be [3][3] matrix.
 
Hope that helps. :)

You are looking for something like this

```
int m =//input;
    int[][] arr = new int[m][m];
for(int i=0;i<m;i++){
    for(int j=0;j<m;j++){
        if(i>=j)
        arr[i][j]=i;
        else
            arr[i][j]=j;
        System.out.print(arr[i][j]);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: You can comment here if something is not clear. If it is, mark this answer correct :)